# Lebesgue measurable <=> outer measure = 0

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset \mathbb R^n$. Then the following two statements hold true:

- $A$ is Lebesgue-measurable.
- It exists $B \in F_{\sigma}$ such that $\lambda_n^* ((A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)) = 0$

Why?

(Where $\lambda_n^*$ is the outer measure.)

Comment: Do you know that Lebesgue measure is regular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If exists an $F_{\sigma}$ set $B$ satisfying the condition then you have that $m(A \setminus B)=m(B \setminus A)=0$

So $A \setminus B,B\setminus A$ are measurable.

Also $ (A \cap B)=B \setminus  (B\setminus A) $

So $(A \cap B)$ is measurable.

From this you can conclude that $A$ is measurable.

The other part is just the regularity of the Lebesgue measure which you can find it in many textbooks.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! Is it also correct that the following is an equivalent statement, too? : It exists $A_1 \in F_{\sigma} , A_2 \in P(\mathbb R^n) $ such that $\lambda_n^* (A_2) = 0 $ and $A= A_1 \cup A_2 $ ?

Comment: Yes...all these facts follow from the regularity of lebesgue measure.

Comment: Thank you very much!